# I have to click the button twice to make the onclick work

Tags: javascript, html, django, redirect, onclick

Here is my html and JS code. When I first click on the button it submits the form but doesn't call the onclick function. I've tried adding onsubmit method to the form and make button type=button. However, that didn't change anything.

The form submission is for Django btw.

```
<form action='' method='GET' required id='form_id'>

     <input class='url_box' type='url' name='url_value' placeholder='Paste the URL...'/> <br>
     <button class='submit-btn' type='submit' onclick="delayRedirect()">Listen</button>

</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function delayRedirect(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = 'player';
    }, 1500);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form required id='form_id'>
     <input class='url_box' type='url' name='url_value' placeholder='Paste the URL...'/> <br>
     <button class='submit-btn'>Listen</button>
</form>
```

/JS

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.sumbit-btn')

btn.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
      e.preventDefault() // becuse the btn in <form></form> 
     // send to Django
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the button type to button, and it logs "clicked." before submitting the form.

```js
$('.submit-btn').click((e) => {
  console.log('clicked.');
  $('form').submit();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='' method='GET' required id='form_id'>

     <input class='url_box' type='url' name='url_value' placeholder='Paste the URL...'/> <br>
     <button class='submit-btn' type='button'>Listen</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form action='' target="you_dont_see_me" method='POST' required id='form_id'>

     <input class='url_box' type='url' name='url_value' placeholder='Paste the URL...'/> <br>
     <button class='submit-btn' type='button' onclick="delayRedirect()">Listen</button>

</form>
<iframe name="you_dont_see_me" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

JS

```
function delayRedirect(){
        document.getElementById('form_id').submit();
    setTimeout(function(){
        //do whatever you want
    }, 1500);
}
```

You can use iframe, but your method needs to be changed to POST.
I personally would use ajax to handle this kind of situation

Comment: This is a pretty good solution but the problem is I need to submit the form first and then delay the redirect because Django makes some kind of conversion in the background.

Comment: I tried your JavaScript Function but I still have to click one more time on the button in order to make the timeout work. The first click only submits the form. This is really weird.